# jQuery/Javascript Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this relatively simple code:

```
var height = help ? 'minus' : 'plus';
var prop = $('#properties');

if(height == 'minus'){
    prop.height(prop.height() -= 206);
} else {
    prop.height(prop.height() += 206);
}
```

It fails on both lines that do the adding/subtracting! Any ideas?

Comment: `-=` tries to subtract `206` from `prop.height()` and assign the result to it. But `prop.height()` returns a value and is not a variable. I assume you just want to omit the `=`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-=` operator equals `operand = operand - value` which in your case would look like

```
prop.height() = prop.height() - 206;
```

which obviously will fail. You just need the minus operator to accomplish that task.

```
prop.height(prop.height() - 206);
```

will do it.

Answer (score 2):

you can't -= a method.

either you need to  `prop.height(prop.height() - 206);`
or collect the value first and then -= it like...

```
var h = prop.height();
h -= 206
 prop.height( h);
```

Answer (score 2):

`prop.height() -= 206` attemtps to assign to the return value, which is not a variable so impossible; same as (`prop.height() = prop.height() - 206`)

You can instead; `prop.height(prop.height() - 206);`

Or (`prop.height(prop.height() + (height === 'minus' ? -206 : 206));`)

Answer (score 1):

```
var height = help ? 'minus' : 'plus';
var prop = $('#properties');
var propHeight = prop.height();

if(height === 'minus'){
    prop.height(propHeight - 206);
} else {
    prop.height(propHeight + 206);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got your answer, but I wanted to mention why bother with an if/else for adding or subtracting:

```
// subtract height if help is true, otherwise add height
var heightmodifier = help ? -1 : 1;
var prop = $('#properties');
var propHeight = prop.height();

prop.height(propHeight + (206 * heightmodifier));
```